# How to change color for 5 seconds?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

i want change of color for 5 seconds
, but this not work

```
DateTimeOffset startTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

            while (true)
            {
                viewAction.BackgroundColor = ColorPalette.Red;
                if (DateTimeOffset.Now.Subtract(startTime).TotalMilliseconds > 5000) {
                    viewAction.BackgroundColor = ColorPalette.Brown;
                    return;
                }

            }
```

Comment: seconds are seconds

Comment: Can you use async/await code in this scope? (ie. await Task.Delay(5000); ChangeColor(); )